# how can I load a data into python jypiternotebook and do apply seaborn codes to that?

Tags: python, seaborn

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Ram N Rom\Desktop\CSVForDate.csv")

sns.histplot(data=df, x='open', y='high')
```

```
ValueError: Could not interpret value `open` for parameter `x`
```

Comment: You probably mean `plt.axes().{x|y}label` instead of `{x|y}='...'`

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html

the parameter `data` must be one of the following:

> pandas.DataFrame, numpy.ndarray, mapping, or sequence

the parameters x or y, must be:

> vectors or keys in `data`

**So please ensure that 'open' and 'high' are both valid keys in your data (also check for case sensitivity like "Open" instead of "open")**

Comment: thank you so much it is worked with case sensitive when I go back and thanks for sharing the link to explore more @nferreira78

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a column named `'open'` and a column named `'high'` in your `df` in order for your code to work. If not, then please update your answer with your df structure so as to reinvestigate your problem.

Just saw @nferreira78 answer which is valid as well.

Comment: yes it is worked with @nferreira78 suggestion. thanks for responding azal